# Nested Aurelia applications

Tags: javascript, aurelia

According to Rob Eisenberg, the creator of Aurelia, it should be possible to have [nested aurelia applications](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/235#issuecomment-152363278) inside each other.

Since the example he mentions in the above link is not public anymore, it'd be very helpful if anyone here could elaborate further, or even link or write a [small example](https://gist.run/?id=7542e061bc940cde506b) of how this sort of nesting would be implemented.

The main application and interface I'm hoping to create with Aurelia would consist of a Windows XP Desktop style-ish shell, in which one would be able to open nested Aurelia applications from the start menu, opening in an embedded window inside the main applications "windows desktop area" - like a windows or file explorer would open in a normal Windows XP OS, but inside the SPA.

To make this truly extendable I would prefer keeping the possibility of placing the nested aurelia applications in folders outside the main applications root folder, and instead linking to them from the main application using a file/folder path on the disk.

So to keep it "simple", imagine [this would be the main application](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/1099_jqui/demo/index.html#) (the windows shell) - clicking the button opens a window, which can be minimized, resized or moved around. In that window another aurelia application would open. And in the end you would hopefully be able to transfer certain state from the main application to the nested apps, like eg. the language or database.

And if possible it would be optimal if the nested application could be located and referenced from outside the main applications root folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=7cda93aa0a225805ddf6**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./child-app"></require>

  <child-app main.bind="main1"></child-app>
  <child-app main.bind="main2"></child-app>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  main1 = './one/app';
  main2 = './two/app';
}
```

**child-app.js**

```js
import {
  Aurelia,
  noView,
  bindable,
  inject,
  Container
} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Loader} from 'aurelia-loader';

@noView()
@inject(Loader, Element)
export class ChildApp {
  @bindable main;

  constructor(loader, element) {
    this.host = element;
    this.app = new Aurelia(this.loader, new Container());
    this.app.use.standardConfiguration();
  }

  mainChanged() {
    this.app.start().then(a => a.setRoot(this.main, this.host));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I only have one last problem now. Since I won't be able to have the folders and files of my nested applications inside the same folder as the main application, something like this main1 = '../sibling-folder-to-main-app-folder/src/app'; isn't working since I'm just getting http://localhost:9000/sibling-folder-to-main-app-folder/src/app.js 404 (Not Found). I can understand why it's saying this, but I can't figure out how I could then have the nested applications in a folder outside the main app root folder? These nested apps are to be separated from main for extensibility.

Comment: So my final question is if it's possible to reference (eg: <child-app main.bind="../../parent-parent-folder-to-main-app-folder/some-module/another-aurelia-app/src/app"></child-app>) a file from a folder outsite the root of an aurelia application? The reason for this is because the aurelia main application is just one part of a bigger core framework, which is to be extensible from modules located else where. :/

Comment: should be possible- it's not really an aurelia thing, that has more to do with your `config.js` for the SystemJS module loader.

Comment: I hope you're right, but so far I haven't been able dig up any info related to this - so I tried to describe the problem as detailed as I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839479/reference-nested-aurelia-app-located-outside-the-main-app-root-folder

Comment: How to make this work with the latest way modules are loaded in the esnext-webpack skeleton, using platform.moduleName etc? I get "Unable to find module with ID...". How to define modules for app1 and app2? I tried changing to this line in child-app.js `this.app.start().then(a => a.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName(this.main), this.host));` but it still didn't work :/

Comment: I've created this repo to illustrate the problem: https://github.com/BruceL33t/skeleton-esnext-webpack-nested-apps